# List Comprehension in 2.4

Tags: python, list, python-2.4, list-comprehension

Am i right to believe that you can only use else in list comprehensions within python 2.5 and higher ?

i.e what would be the best way to achieve the following in 2.4 ?

```
print [x if x != "3" else "1" + "3" for x in ["1","2","3"]]
```

Comment: I always thought list comprehensions were harder to grasp than standard loops... unpacking a list comprehension seems pretty straight forward.  Maybe it's just me.

Comment: @monkut: Though as far as I know, a list comprehension runs faster then a standard for loop because it can be evaluated as an expression? That is my best understanding. So it can be optimized.

Comment: The `else` is not part of the list comprehension syntax. You have a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) inside a list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the conditional expression is new in python 2.5.  One old workaround is to use:

```
("13",x)[x!=3]
```

What this does is it creates a tuple (`("1",x)`) and then indexes it with a boolean value (`True` (`1`) or `False` (`0`)).

Putting it all together you get:

```
[("13",x)[x!="3"] for x in ("1","2","3")]
```

---

This idiom is pretty hard to read and it's worth asking yourself if you actually *need* to support python2.4.  A slightly more verbose alternative is to use a function:

```
def conditional_expr(a,cond,b):
    if cond:
        return a
    else:
        return b
```

In other words:

```
[conditional_expr(x,x!='3','13') for x in ("1","2","3")]
```

Of course, none of these actually compares to the conditional expression which is able to short circuit (e.g. if the condition is `True`, you don't need to evaluate the return value if it is `False`)

Comment: In this case, the original poster's code would be: `print [("13", x)[x!="3"] for x in ["1","2","3"]]`

Comment: Note that this may not work for all cases because one has to evaluate the values for both possible outcomes (condition met / condition not met) all the time. For example `float(x) if x != '-' else None` can't be translated that way because one has to evaluate `float('-')` before testing.

Comment: @AndreHolzner -- Yes, that's what I was alluding to in the last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

I dont't know about list comprehensions in 2.4. But a classical for loop will do in any case.

```
l = []
for x in ["1","2","3"]:
    if x != "3":
        l.append(x)
    else:
        l.append("1" + "3")
print l
```

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of map...

```
In [38]: def f(x):
   ....:     if x != "3":
   ....:         return x
   ....:     else:
   ....:         return "1" + "3"
   ....:

In [39]: map(f, ["1", "2", "3"])
Out[39]: ['1', '2', '13']
```

another approach as suggested by 'Janne Karila'

```
In [40]: [f(x) for x in ["1", "2", "3"]]
Out[40]: ['1', '2', '13']
```

Comment: `map` is a good tool for this, but one could also keep the list comprehension and use `f` in it: `[f(x) for x in ["1","2","3"]]`

Answer (score 0):

You need a full `for` loop, and you only need to test one `if` statement:

```
results = []
for x in ["1","2","3"]:
    if x == "3":
        x = "1" + "3"
    results.append(x)
```

Some of the python2.4 compatible "one liner conditionals" are not worth (I think) the confusing way they read.